# What is difference between had been wanting and have been wanting

Tags: present-perfect

I meet a friend after years of waiting. What should I tell her:-

> 1. I **had been wanting** to meet you for a really long time
> 2. I **have been wanting** to meet you for a really long time.

and Can I replace the word wanting with longing??

Answer (score 1):

**Had** been wanting expresses a past event that is no longer occurring in the present, meaning you no longer want to meet the person.

**Have** been wanting expresses a past event that is still occurring in the present.

You would say:

> I have been wanting to meet you for a long time.

You could replace **wanting** with **longing**, however, *longing* is more intense than *wanting* and may sound a little odd. It's not as common in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

**I had been wanting** would be something you would use when explaining to a friend about your previous 'wanting' of something, but not necessarily something you are still 'wanting' today. Example:

> Katie, I had been wanting (in the past) for us to be lovers until the day we die,
>   but now I am indifferent since you cheated on me!

**I have been wanting** is something you are 'wanting' in the present or in actively recent times. Example:

> Katie, I have been wanting to tell you something for weeks now. Will
>   you pop that zit on your forehead? It's creeping me out, yo